# Why would Din Djarin be tracked before he had the armour?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In season 1, episode 5: “The Gunslinger”, Din Djarin is on Tatooine fighting Fennec Shand. At the end of that episode, someone walks up to her, but we cannot see their face.

> Waaaay later, in season 2, episode 6: “The Tragedy”, we find out that she has been saved by Boba Fett, who says that he has been tracking Din Djarin. Boba watched Din Djarin receive his old armour from Cobb Vanth in season 2, episode 1. The obvious assumption is that Boba Fett just wants his armour back, BUT the timeline doesn't match up. Din hasn't had the armour very long... It looks like Boba Fett's been on his trail even before he had the armour. How or why would he be tracking him since Chapter 5?

Comment: Maybe Bobba wasn't tracking him for the armour, he was tracking a fellow Mandalorian and bounty hunter but was obliged to reveal himself after Din took possession of his armour.

Answer (score 1):

Spoilers ahead.

By the time we reach Episode 5, Din is a wanted man for betraying the Bounty Hunter's Guild. Plus he is known as THE Mandalorian. We don't see a lot of them to begin with. It would make sense Boba would keep tabs on someone like that when he could. It's also possible he thought Din had his armor already (I mean, normal people wouldn't know the difference, since Din keeps asking people for information about "his kind").

The catch here is there's nothing to indicate Boba was tracking Din. We know [why Boba was on Tatooine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nAnkFVaKnec), but he didn't necessarily *have* to be tracking Din. As a bounty hunter, Boba might have wanted to catch her himself, or he might have simply been in the area later. As to why Boba shows up in Episode 9(S2E1), if Din has heard of this "Mandalorian", Boba certainly would have, and Din beat him to the punch.